# Disable typein for UserField

Tags: people-picker

We have a customer who would like to disable the ability for end users to type in values directly for a UserField control in a page layout. They would like the users to only use the adress book.

We have the similar functionality on another site but there we use the PeopleEditor control. That control have the attribute AllowTypeIn which gives us the ability to force the users to use the Adress book instead.

How would I achieve the same functionality for a UserField? Should I use a script or can I do some override of the UserField control?

/Niclas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code. you will need jQuery for that:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('table.ms-usereditor div.ms-inputuserfield').attr('contenteditable', 'false')
});
```

for deployment you can use CustomAction as described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb9b0c92-cee3-48e1-949e-562165fb9a65)

Answer (score 0):

Declare your field in markup as this:

```
 <SharePoint:UserField ID="UfEmployee" runat="server" FieldName="Employee"/>
```

To Disable use this code in OnPrerender:

```
   var ppe = (PeopleEditor)UfEmployee.TemplateContainer.FindControl("UserField");
   ppe.Enabled = false;
```